# Loading multiple files Exception error C#

Tags: c#, exception, readfile

I am making the game minesweeper and I am trying to implement a highScores feature. I am trying to load 3 different files (each one holds the high scores for each of the 3 difficulty settings) into 3 different richTextBox's. When I run the app and click the 'high scores' tab from the menu strip it works the first time. However if I play a game and then try to access the high scores form I get an Exception error -

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\jzcon_000\Copy\Visual
>   Studio\Projects\Assignment1\Assignment1\bin\Debug\highScoresMed.txt'
>   because it is being used by another process

This is where the call is made

```
    private void highScoresToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Minesweeper.HighSc highScore = new Minesweeper.HighSc();
        highScore.read();
        highScore.Show();   
    }
```

This is the method in my HighSc class

```
    public void read()
    {
        StreamReader readerE = File.OpenText("highScoresEasy.txt");
        StreamReader readerM = File.OpenText("highScoresMed.txt");
        StreamReader readerH = File.OpenText("highScoresHard.txt");

        if (readerE != null)
        {
            string readEasy = File.ReadAllText("highScoresEasy.txt");
            richTextBox1.Text = readEasy;
        }
        readerE.Close();

        if (readerM != null)
        {
            string readMed = File.ReadAllText("highScoresMed.txt");
            richTextBox2.Text = readMed;
        }
        readerM.Close();

        if (readerH != null)
        {
            string readHard = File.ReadAllText("highScoresHard.txt");
            richTextBox3.Text = readHard;
        }
        readerH.Close();
    }
```

Heres the save high scores class

```
namespace Minesweeper
{
 class Save
 {
    int diff, hr, min, sec;
    string player;

    public Save(int difficulty, int hour, int minute, int second, string playerN)
    {
        diff = difficulty;
        hr = hour;
        min = minute;
        sec = second;
        player = playerN;
    }

    public void save()
    {
        StreamWriter writerEasy = new StreamWriter("highScoresEasy.txt", true);
        StreamWriter writerMed = new StreamWriter("highScoresMed.txt", true);
        StreamWriter writerHard = new StreamWriter("highScoresHard.txt", true);

        if (diff == 1)
        {
            writerEasy.WriteLine("Time: " + hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + "Name: " + player);
            writerEasy.Close();
        }
        else if (diff == 2)
        {
            writerMed.WriteLine("Time: " + hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + "Name: " + player);
            writerMed.Close();
        }
        else if (diff == 3)
        {
            writerHard.WriteLine("Time: " + hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + "Name: " + player);
            writerHard.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: not sure why the downvotes.  This is a valid, legitimate question, and even though it's very obviously a homework question, it's worded a lot better than most, and actually has related code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you have the difficulty level set to 1 and then save, you open the StreamWriters for both the level2 and level3 but never close them.

This could only mean that when you try to load the highscore for these two levels you will find your files locked by your previous save.

You should change your Save method to open only the required file

```
public void save()
{
    if (diff == 1)
    {
        using(StreamWriter writerEasy = new StreamWriter("highScoresEasy.txt", true))
        {
            writerEasy.WriteLine("Time: " + hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + "Name: " + player);
        }
    }
    else if (diff == 2)
    ....
    else if (diff == 3)
    ....
```

I suggest also to use the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) in your reading method to be sure that also in case of exceptions the stream are correctly disposed